# How to handle laravel csrf when sending a Guzzle POST request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, guzzle

I'm trying to send a POST request with Guzzle to a remote Laravel server. The problem is that the request will always be rejected due to the default Laravel csrf middleware.

The request is used to forward an image file that a user uploads from the main server to a server for storing images.

Is there a way to set the correct token using Guzzle?

If not would it be safe to turn off the csrf middleware for the images server as it only recieves requests from another server?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying a remote Laravel server, CSRF tokens can't be expected. CSRF tokens are for web pages generated by the same laravel code.

1. You can switch off CSRF token for this route at `/app/Http/Midddleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`, by updating:

> protected $except = [    'your-image-route-url' ];

2. Handling authentication via API tokens (Authorization: Bearer  / Or Passport)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a CSRF token before sending the request and adding it in the header as `X-CSRF-Token`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: The doc is quite well explained http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers

Comment: inthe headers set X-XSRF-TOKEN => csrf_token()

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but simple answer is, you cannot successfully verify this request, at least, as for laravel 5.5 LTS.

So, if you want to handle your POST request, either pass right token to it (which is impossible in your guzzle request), or remove csrf checking from midlleware VerifCsrfToken.

You can do it, by including your route to `protected $except` in your /app/Http/Midddleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php file...

Unless your request is coming from other sites, you are probably doing something wrong...